# How to enable Amazon S3 Files Protection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a web application with two mobile(Android & iOs) based applications of the same. Currently the files uploaded are open to all, which in terms means that anyone with the direct image link can open it using a web browser.

How can I protect or limit the file access to the users of my mobile applications or web application ?

NB: As a beginner, I am not sure about the configuration details to be provided along with question, If I need to give more details on my s3 config. please specify it, I can add it to the s question to make the question more meaningful, so sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Cloudfront and signed URLs, and set up access controls on the origin

Comment: @Henry Thank you, Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Actually, unfortunately not. I've never done it myself. But in effect, you set up CloudFront pointed to your Origin (S3?), lock down S3 so it only allows CloudFront to access it, and then use signed URLs in CloudFront so you can expire every, say, 24 hours the image links. Unfortunately that's all I know! But if you google about signed urls + cloudfront + s3 origin I'm sure you can find it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier approach than pre-signed urls would be to use Amazon Cognito to provide access to AWS resources to your trusted applications, even to unauthenticated users.

To do this you would create an [Identity Pool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html) for your application (just need one pool for all 3 of your clients) and then configure it so that when a client provides a valid Identity Pool Id they can assume an IAM role with permissions to access AWS resources.

Then you control what S3 bucket permissions the IAM role they assume would have - you could allow unauthenticated users access to read the S3 objects, or force them to create accounts to be able to read/write to S3 buckets (this is very easy with Cognito - users can sign up with facebook, gmail, their own email, etc.)

[There's a step-by-step guide here for setting up an identity pool with Cognito, and then allowing unauthenticated users to assume an IAM role that can access the contents of an S3 bucket](https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-amazon-s3-to-android-tutorial/)

The above causes the same set of permissions for all guest user accounts - that have assumed an IAM role through Amazon Cognito by identifying themselves as part of an identity pool.

**edit**: I should point out that if you authenticate via Cognito, you'll need to access the S3 bucket through the [S3 Transfer Manager from the AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html)