# How to generate secured URLs for

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, servlets, amazon-s3, jwt

I am uploading items to `Amazon S3` using the Java SDK. Some of the items I upload need to be public where I can access by a public URL while some others are there which need to be private. Please check the below code.

```
public class FileUpload {

    public static int PUBLIC = 1;
    public static int PRIVATE = 2;

    public void UploadObjectSingleOperation(String bucketName, InputStream inputStream, String fileName, int privacy) {

        String keyName = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        String secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyName, secret);
        AmazonS3 s3client=null;

        if(privacy==PUBLIC)
        {
            s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
        }
        else if(privacy==PRIVATE)
        {
            s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
        }


        try {
            System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");

            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, inputStream,null).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));

        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which "
                    + "means your request made it "
                    + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response"
                    + " for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which "
                    + "means the client encountered "
                    + "an internal error while trying to "
                    + "communicate with S3, "
                    + "such as not being able to access the network.");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

For the private objects, how can I get secured URL, like a "tokenized" one? That means, the URL exists but it require some special validation to "work" or "allow access", so not everyone can access the URL but my app. How can I do this?

I looked at `Signed URLs` at S3 but it only set up an expiration date/time. My URL need not expire, but some access validation.

Answer (score 0):

After uploading to s3, you need to use the s3client to request an pre-signed url for the object by bucket/key.

[Note that the longest you can have these pre-signed urls work is 7 days, after which they will expire](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html):

> A presigned URL can be valid for a maximum of seven days because the signing key you use in signature calculation is valid for up to seven days.

The AWS docs have an example for how to [generate these urls from java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html):

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()); 

java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long msec = expiration.getTime();
msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour.
expiration.setTime(msec);

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
              new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); // Default.
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL s = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, as mentioned in my question,signed URL can be accessed by anyone as well, I am looking for a mechanism where the S3 require to "authenticate" the URL access from somehow. The contents of these private URLs will be displayed in the android app for the "paid users" and I don't want them to somehow get the URL and hand over to someone who has not made a payment.

Comment: @PeakGen - Ah ok, I answered that question here for another user: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43864225/808532 - the process amounts to using Amazon Cognito so only users of your app have access to certain buckets, and it avoids the need to even have pre-signed urls. This works even if you don't require users to sign into your app